# Como pegar o Unix Timestamp com JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Tentei aqui de algumas formas, mas parece estar errada. Um exemplo do que eu faço:

```
var data = new Date();
var timestamp = data.getTime() / 1000;
```

Essa forma está correta?

Comment: Uma dica. Ele pode mudar se o dispositivo estiver que a hora errada. E cada lugar tem sua hora. Aqui pode ser 7:22 ali já é 8:22. aconselho você fazer um Timestamp com uma linguagem que o aeu servidor aceita. Assim fica tudo fixo e sem bug's

Comment: A minha pergunta era a respeito de como eu poderia pegar o Unix Timestamp e pelo que eu vi nessa pergunta antiga sobre o mesmo assunto, ele não especificou qual Timestamp ele estava querendo obter. Aquela resposta não seria satisfatória para o meu caso, pois, no meu caso eu teria que dividir por 1000. O JavaScript pelo que eu percebi trabalha com milissegundos e no meu caso eu precisaria converter para segundos para poder acessar uma API, essa diferença me deixou confuso por isso eu perguntei aqui.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Correto. Só faltou arredondar.

Timestamp em milisegundos:

```
+new Date() //que é o mesmo que new Date().getTime()
```

Timestamp em segundos:

```
Math.floor(+new Date() / 1000) //que o mesmo que Math.floor(new Date().getTime()/1000)
```